# Which of dB or dBA are more useful for predicting damage to hearing?

Tags: human-biology, human-anatomy, hearing

With no information about noise other than its loudness measured in decibels or in A-weighted decibels, which can be used to more accurately predict how much hearing damage may be caused?

Even though dBA is more accurate for how loud something sounds to humans, that doesn't give me any confidence to say that that also means our ears are under more mechanical/physical trauma.